# How to assign return value of a promise to object key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    $scope.modelTmp = {
        appData.getAppDataItem({'@key': 'last_news_sync_date'}).then( function (x) {
                    $scope.modelTmp.useMobileDataTmp = x; })
        console.log($scope.modelTmp.useMobileDataTmp);
```

I want to assign `x` to `useMobileData`. Please help me to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign it synchronously, you can only do so in the callback:

```
$scope.modelTmp = {}

appData.getAppDataItem({'@key': 'last_news_sync_date'}).then(function (x) {
    $scope.modelTmp.useMobileDataTmp = x;
});
```

Comment: Once you go out of the `.then()` it is `undefined` I think. I am getting it as `undefined`. See my edited code. The `console()` message is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to wait until the promise is resolved and then inside the callback assign it to the modelTmp object. At the moment you're just assigning the promise to the modelTmp.useMobileDataTmp.

See below for how to assign in the callback

```
$scope.modelTmp = {};

appData.getAppDataItem({'@key': 'last_news_sync_date'}).then( function(x) {
  $scope.modelTmp.useMobileDataTmp = x;
})
```

Comment: But when print it outside of `.then()`, I am getting it as `undefined`. See my edited code in the question

Comment: Well it's not defined outside of the .then() so you're getting undefined as the result